# Google+ Signin/Singup button

Tags: api, authentication, google-plus

I would like to add a Google + signin/signup button to my website [www.bendali.co.za](http://www.bendali.co.za). I have already put in this code:

```
    <!-- Place this asynchronous JavaScript just before your </body> tag -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();


function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['access_token']) {
    // Successfully authorized
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
    document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
  } else if (authResult['error']) {
    // There was an error.
    // Possible error codes:
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
    // console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}


    </script>

<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="712370252357.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">

</span>
</span>
```

I have taken it from https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/. But when I press it, it gives me the dialog and everything and I accept it and the button dissapears (all of which is normal). But it doesn't log me in or anything. How would I get it to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issues with your code and a quick test on my machine shows it working.

You can test whether you are logged in by opening the JavaScript console for your web browser and trying to get the access token for the current session. The following function:

```
gapi.auth.getToken();
```

Will return *null* if you are not logged in and something like this:

```
Object {state: "", access_token: "ya29.lkjasdlkjasd....", token_type: "Bearer", expires_in: "3600", code: "4/.....wo8WbjRKPN4WMqTmHjyTFGPeKJnufgI"…}
```

if you are logged in.  The console also should give you more information about any errors that are preventing the sign-in code from working.

If you are looking to do something more complicated such as log the user into your site, you should start with the [Google+ Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart) to get the gist of how you can connect your server with the authorized user and then [take a look at Photohunt](https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt) for a more comprehensive site example.

Comment: So did you manage to log in? I mean did it tell you that you were logged in?

Comment: What do you mean by log you in?  The short version is that you are in an "authorized" state after successfully signing in. Once you are in an authorized state, your app can make API calls to Google on behalf of the user (get user's display name, list the people visible to your app, and so on).

Comment: To reflect a user being logged in, we recommend making a people.get API call in the sign-in callback so that you can fetch the user's name and profile image to greet them. At this point, you can already make API calls on behalf of the user, though. To learn more about greeting the user, tune in to our Google+ Developers Live episode today at 2:30pm PST. (https://plus.google.com/events/cblr79ob8a042sjg64jgf93ka20)

Comment: Thanks for the help, what I mean by login is that they will be able to write posts for example or do something that a user of bendali.co.za can do.

Comment: If you want to connect them with your site, you will need to do more work than simply authorizing them. You should check out the Google+ quickstarts to see if this gets you closer in your server-side language: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart